# How to change values before text in string using R

Tags: r, string, gsub, string-substitution

I have multiple strings that are similar to the following pattern:

```
dat<-("00000000AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0")
```

I need to change all 0 values to "." before the first character value within a string. My desired output in this example would be:

"........AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0".

I tried using gsub to accomplish this task:

```
gsub("\\G([^_\\d]*)\\d", ".\\1", dat, perl=T)
```

Unfortunately it changed all of the 0s to "." instead of the 0s preceding the first "A".

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Why not `gsub("\\G0", ".", dat, perl=T)`? Looks like all you need is replace the initial zeros in the string. Or could you please share some more examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to simply replace  each leading `0` with a `.`, you can use

```r
gsub("\\G0", ".", dat, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, `\G0` matches a `0` char at the start of string, and then every time after a successful match. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0cUuk3/2).

If you need to replace each `0` in a string before the first letter you can use

```r
gsub("\\G[^\\p{L}0]*\\K0", ".", dat, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, `\G` matches start of string or end of the preceding successful match, `[^\p{L}0]*` matches zero or more chars other than a letter and `0`, then `\K` omits the matched text, and then `0` matches the `0` char and it is replaced with a `.`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0cUuk3/1).

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/ZihYAP):

```r
dat <- c("00000000AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0","102030405000AZD")
gsub("\\G0", ".", dat, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "........AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0"
## [2] "102030405000AZD"                                         
gsub("\\G[^\\p{L}0]*\\K0", ".", dat, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "........AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0"
## [2] "1.2.3.4.5...AZD"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard.
So I tried to do it with a custom function:

```
library(stringr)

dat<-("00000000AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0")

Zero_Replacer <- function(x) {
  x <- str_split(x, '[A-Za-z]', 2)
  x[[1]][1] <- str_replace_all(x[[1]][1], "0", ".")
  paste0(x[[1]][1], x[[1]][2])
}

Zero_Replacer(dat)
```

Output:

```
[1] "........AAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD0"
```